# How to efficiently extract data in bulk from an RDBMS for parent entities that have multiple child entities

Tags: sql

In my application I have an IncidentReport.  The IncidentReport has a few scalar fields and also several collections of other entities.  I need to make extracts available of many thousands of these IncidentReports with complete details in some format such as JSON or XML.  The amount of data is so large that I want to be able to stream the results so that I don't have to read them all into memory before sending them out via the API.

The IncidentReports have the following fields:

```
id
startTime
endTime
leadAgent
camerasUsed (Collection)
notes (Collection)
groupsAssigned (Collection)
widgetsUsed (Collection)
```

A set of fully populated IncidentReports might look like this:

```
IncidentReport1  
    id=1
    startTime=12121212
    endTime=12121214
    leadAgent="Joe"
    camerasUsed
        Camera1
            camId=1
            camName="Camera1"
            camLocation="Office #123"
        Camera2
            camId=2
            camName="Fred"
            camLocation="Outer space"
    notes
        Note1
            operatorName="Sam"
            operatorId=1234
            noteText="I said hello to the customer"
        Note2
            operatorName="Joe"
            operatorId=322
            noteText="Good job"
    groupsAssigned
        Group1
            groupId=222
            groupName="Red Team"
        Group2
            groupId=223
            groupName="Blue Team"
        Group3
            groupId=224
            groupName="Yellow Team"
    widgetsUsed
        Widget1
            widgetId=123
            widgetName="A widget"
            widgetUse="Tightened"
        Widget2
            widgetId=124
            widgetName="Another widget"
            widgetUse="Loosened"
IncidentReport2  
    id=2
    startTime=12123445
    endTime=12123999
    leadAgent="Karen"
    camerasUsed
        Camera3
            camId=345
            camName="Camera3"
            camLocation="Office #2323"
        Camera12
            camId=12
            camName="Jane's Cam"
            camLocation="Inner space"
    notes
        Note1
            operatorName="Jeff"
            operatorId=32323
            noteText="How is the case going?"
    groupsAssigned
        Group1
            groupId=223
            groupName="Red Team"
    widgetsUsed
        Widget1
            widgetId=223
            widgetName="Super widget"
            widgetUse="Unknown"
```

The  IncidentReport is stored in an RDMS along with its child entities in a normalized form.  So there are the following tables:

```
IncidentReport(id [PK], startTime, endTime, leadAgent)
IRCameras(incidentId [FK], camId, camName, camLocation)
IRNotes(incidentId [FK], operatorName, operatorId, noteText)
IRGroupsAssigned(incidentId [FK], groupId, groupName)
IRWidgetsUsed(incidentId [FK], widgetId, widgetName, widgetUse)
```

I have found that it is very inefficient to iterate through all of the IncidentReports and select the associated cameras, notes groups, and widgets.  This leads to the N+1 selects problem where I get an enormous number of select statements executed.  (I was using Hibernate for this.)

I don't think I can use a single select statement with a bunch of outer joins because the number of columns would be enormous to accomodate all of the fields of all of the child entities (camera, notes, groups, and widgets) and there would be a lot of redundant data returned.

The only thing I can think to do for efficiency sake is to query each table separately and stream the data in a "normalized" form so that the IncidentReports with only the scalar values would appear first, followed by all of the cameras, then all of the notes, then all of the groups, and then all of the widgets.  The caller would be required to reconstruct the fully populated IncidentReports by interleaving the various collections by the parent IncidentReport id.

Is there a way to accomplish this efficiently while still streaming the results as fully populated IncidentReports as in my first example above?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered outputing the query as XML? I am not sure what RDBMS you are using, but a SQL-Server example would be:

```
CREATE TABLE #IncidentReport(id INT, startTime DATETIME, endTime DATETIME, leadAgent VARCHAR(20))
CREATE TABLE #IRCameras(incidentId INT, camId INT, camName VARCHAR(50), camLocation VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #IRNotes(incidentId INT, operatorName VARCHAR(50), operatorId INT, noteText VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #IRGroupsAssigned(incidentId INT, groupId INT, groupName VARCHAR(50))
CREATE TABLE #IRWidgetsUsed(incidentId INT, widgetId INT, widgetName VARCHAR(50), widgetUse VARCHAR(50))

INSERT #IncidentReport VALUES (1, GETDATE()-2, GETDATE()-1, 'Joe'), (2, GETDATE(), GETDATE()+1, 'Karen')
INSERT #IRCameras VALUES (1, 1, 'Camera1', 'Office #123'), (1, 2, 'Camera2', 'Outer Space'), (2, 345, 'Camera3', 'Office #2323'), (2, 12, 'Jane''s Cam', 'Inner Space')
INSERT #IRNotes VALUES (1, 'Sam', 1234, 'I said Hello to the Customer'), (1, 'Joe', 322, 'Good Job'), (2, 'Jeff', 32323, 'How is the case going')
INSERT #IRGroupsAssigned VALUES (1, 222, 'Red Team'), (1, 223, 'Blue Team'), (1, 224, 'Yellow Team'), (2, 222, 'Red Team')
INSERT #IRWidgetsUsed VALUES (1, 123, 'A widget', 'Tightened'), (1, 122, 'Another widget', 'Loosened'), (2, 223, 'Super widget', 'Unknown')

SELECT  ID,
        StartTime,
        EndTime,
        LeadAgent,
        (   SELECT  CamID, CamName, CamLocation
            FROM    #IRCameras c
            WHERE   ir.ID = c.IncidentID
            FOR XML PATH('Cameras'), TYPE
        ),
        (   SELECT  OperatorName, OperatorID, NoteText
            FROM    #IRNotes n
            WHERE   ir.ID = n.IncidentID
            FOR XML PATH('Notes'), TYPE
        ),
        (   SELECT  GroupID, GroupName
            FROM    #IRGroupsAssigned g
            WHERE   ir.ID = g.IncidentID
            FOR XML PATH('GroupsAssigned'), TYPE
        ),
        (   SELECT  WidgetID, WidgetName, WidgetUse
            FROM    #IRWidgetsUsed w
            WHERE   ir.ID = w.IncidentID
            FOR XML PATH('WidgetsUsed'), TYPE
        )
FROM    #IncidentReport IR
FOR XML PATH ('IncidentReport'), ROOT

DROP TABLE #IncidentReport
DROP TABLE #IRCameras
DROP TABLE #IRNotes
DROP TABLE #IRGroupsAssigned
DROP TABLE #IRWidgetsUsed
```

Not sure if you can apply any of this logic to your situation but it has been 7 hours and nobody has posted any other ideas so thought I would throw this out there.

Comment: That is an interesting solution.  I have to support SQLServer and Postgres in my app so I am hoping for something that is standard SQL rather than an extension.  There is some XML support in postgres but the performance doesnt seem to be very good.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to propose a possible answer that I am not sure I like.  What if I open multiple cursors on the database simultaneously.  So I would have the following cursors:

```
IncidentReportCursor
IRCamerasCursor
IRNotesCursor
IRGroupsAssignedCursor
IRWidgetsUsedCursor
```

Then I could iterate the cursors at the same time and build my result set as I go by interleaving the collections into each IncidentReport entity as in the sample code below.  Is this a crazy idea, to have multiple cursors, or is it reasonable?

```
Statement irStat = conn.createStatement();
Statement irCamStat = conn.createStatement();
Statement irNoteStat = conn.createStatement();
irStat.setFetchSize(100);
irCamStat.setFetchSize(100);
irNoteStat.setFetchSize(100);

ResultSet irRS = irStat.executeQuery("select * from IncidentReport order by id");
ResultSet irCamRS = irCamStat.executeQuery("select * from IRCameras order by incidentId");
ResultSet irNotesRS = irNoteStat.executeQuery("select * from IRNotes order by incidentId");

int lastCamIncidentId = -1;
int lastNotesIncidentId = -1;

while(irRS.next()) {
    IncidentReport ir = new IncidentReport();
    populateIR(irRS, ir);

    // iterate the notes results until we catch up to the current id
    while(!irCamsRS.isClosed() && lastCamIncidentId <= ir.getId()) { 
       if(irCamsRS.next()) {
           IRCam irCam = new IRCam();
           populateCam(irCamsRS, itrCam);
           lastCamIncidentId = irCam.getIncidentReportId();
           if(lastCamIncidentId == ir.getId()) {
              ir.addCam(irCam);
           }
        }
    } 

    // iterate the notes results until we catch up to the current id
    while(!irNotesRS.isClosed() && lastNotesIncidentId <= ir.getId()) { 
       if(irNotesRS.next()) {
           IRNote irNote = new IRNote();
           populateNote(irNotesRS, itrNote);
           lastNotesIncidentId = irNote.getIncidentReportId();
           if(lastNotesIncidentId == ir.getId()) {
              ir.addNote(irNote);
           }
        }
    } 

    serializeIncidentReport(ir);
}
```